# Symfony2 KNP Pagination "Cannot count query "

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pagination, knppaginator

So , i'm working on a news portal . I'm using KNP Paginator,and i've got an error :
**Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction**

And now , my source code :

```
    #block of code from controller

    $rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NickCoreBundle:News');
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $rep->getNewsFeedQuery($user->getId()),
        $page,
        10
    );
```

and from my repository:

```
public function getNewsFeedQuery($userid)
{
    $userid = intval($userid);

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('n')
        ->from('NickCoreBundle:News', 'n')
        ->innerJoin('NickCoreBundle:Subscriptions', 's', 'WITH', 's.user = :userid AND n.source = s.source')
        ->orderBy("n.date","DESC")
        ->setParameter('userid', $userid)->getQuery();
}
```

how to solve it :) ? tried to get result from query , in ArrayCollection , it works (partialy,not sorted by date , and i think this method used a lot of time)

Comment: Shouldn't you be grouping by `news.id`? (e.g. `->groupBy('n.id')`)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late to answer but it could be of help to other readers.
I would suggest doing away with the explicit *innerJoin*  and let Doctrine handle the joins.

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('n')
    ->from('NickCoreBundle:News', 'n')
    ->join('n.source', 's')
    ->where('s.user'= :userid )
    ->orderBy("n.date","DESC")
    ->setParameter('userid', $userid)->getQuery();
```